# npm run dev error for npx mix in bootstrap for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-5, npx

I installed bootstrap 5 and also installed the dependency required `@popperjs/core` but still after doing that it still brought out for me from the ./nodemodules.
I would appreciate any assistance on how to clear this error

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '~bootstrap/css/bootstrap' in 'C:\Sites\firstProject\resources\css'
    at finishWithoutResolve (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:293:18)
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:362:15
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43       
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at processResult (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:713:19)        
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:5
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\Sites\firstProject\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:155:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap did you install? In 4.6 you should use `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` instead. In 5.* versions also that path.